# How to get and decode windows 10 20H2 product key from windows registry?

Tags: windows, key, registry, product, registration

Everything I can find online works something like the code here https://gist.github.com/Spaceghost/877110.  This does not work on Windows 10 20H2.  The code runs but produces an erroneous result.

I need to know:

- where in the registry am I supposed to get the product key from in binary?
- how do I decode it (preferably but not necessarily in python)?

Comment: Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the registry is not a public programming interface. What is the *real* problem you need to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable Initially I was trying trying to get win product key with python, but I found another way to do this, so at this point I'm just mad I couldn't figure it out.  People used to know how to do it, so I was just wondering if anyone did now.